# Accuracy measures in training/test split of time series

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting

I'm using [Forecast Principles and Practice 2](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/toolbox-exercises.html) to study time series and a doubt came in mind while I was trying to do exercise 7 of chapter 3.

> How sensitive are the accuracy measures to the training/test split?

The r code is

```
retaildata <- readxl::read_excel("retail.xlsx", skip=1)
myts <- ts(retaildata[,"A3349873A"], frequency=12, start=c(1982,4))
x1 <- window(myts, end=c(2010,12))
x2 <- window(myts, start=2011)
autoplot(cbind(x1,x2))
f1 <- snaive(x1)
accuracy(f1,x2)
checkresiduals(f1)
```

The output is

```
                    ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE      MAPE
Training set  7.772973 20.24576 15.95676  4.702754  8.109777
Test set     55.300000 71.44309 55.78333 14.900996 15.082019
                 MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
Training set 1.000000 0.7385090        NA
Test set     3.495907 0.5315239  1.297866
```

The errors are minor in the training set, but is this not expected? I do not know if I understood correctly what the word "sensitive" means in this case.

I thought it would only make sense to compare the accuracy between different forecasting methods and based on test sets.

Comment: It's a good question. My first idea would be to look at other *time points* where you could split the training and test sample and see whether the test errors differ by much. You could try that. Or ask the FPP2 authors for clarification.